# Best way to copy a vector to a list in STL?

Tags: c++, stl

Is iterating through the vector using an iterator and copying to a list the most optimal method of copying. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Why would you iterate and not use the standard copy algorithm?

```
std::copy( vector.begin(), vector.end(), std::back_inserter( list ) );
```

Comment: Should be std::copy rather than stl::copy, but otherwise this is the preferred method when using iterators to copy.

Answer (score 71):

If you're making a new list, you can take advantage of a constructor that takes begin and end iterators:

```
std::list<SomeType> myList(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Kasprzol's answer is perfect if you have an existing list you want to append to.

Comment: Is it faster than 

std::copy( vector.begin(), vector.end(), std::back_inserter( list ) );

?

What's the difference under the hood?

Comment: I doubt it would be any slower, and it may be able to optimize things a bit better. Standard library implementations vary, so it's hard to say for sure. Profile it if it's important to you.

Answer (score 10):

```
list.assign(vector.begin(), vector.end());
```

Comment: This is helpful, but you should probably add some non-code to this answer to avoid a potential VLQ flag.

Answer (score 3):

I like this suggestion for constructing a new list.

```
std::list<SomeType> myList(v.begin(), v.end());
```

But when appending to an existing list, the following may be optimal for small data sets.  By "optimal", I mean that it is easiest to remember how to do and easiest to understand.  (These are subjective statements, I'm sure it depends on how your brain is wired.)

```
for ( unsigned i=0; i<v.size(); i++ ) myList.push_back(v[i]);
```

Using iterators on vectors may be overly pedantic in many cases.  Simple indexing usually works fine.

Another thread addresses iterators vs. indices ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131241/why-use-iterators-instead-of-array-indices)).  In that thread, the taken answer basically preferred iterators because they are more generic.  But if vectors are the most commonly used container type, I think it is reasonable to specialize this kind of simple algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use trickier things from the `<algorithm>` header, for example `for_each` or `copy` ... but they would amount to the same thing, in my opinion.

Comment: for_each will amount to the same. Copy can be overloaded to provide much more efficient copy mechanics depending on the iterators provided, and is generally the preferred mechanism.