# Are Iterators faster than array[i]?

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, arrayiterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use iterators instead of array indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131241/why-use-iterators-instead-of-array-indices)

Because for the life of me I can't figure out how they're not redundant.

```
vector<string>::iterator iter1
vector<string>::const_iterator iter2
```

Maybe they're faster?

Comment: measure in the context you care of is the only valid answer.

Comment: Depending on the actual container, incrementing an iterator might be faster than indexing (think linked lists). The actual reason is what sixlettervariables wrote in his answer.

Comment: @Tamás: ... along with the other two answerers.

Comment: @Alexandre: Woops, my search for a duplicate was evidently pretty poor. Looking at *Related* on the RHS shows I'm an idiot :)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal there were no other answers when I wrote the comment, but yeah.

Answer (score 7):

Iterators aren't intended to be faster, they're intended to be as fast, which they are, and significantly more generic. `array[i]` is only valid for an array- not a linked list.

Comment: So that's what it's about. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Iterators allow container independent algorithms to be developed. This way something like `std::sort` doesn't really have to care whether it is a `vector` or `your_datastructure_here` as long as it meets the appropriate iterator requirements.

Consider finding the maximum in a `list`, `vector`, or bare array.

```
int A[...];         // ...some array
std::list<int> L;   // ...some list
std::vector<int> V; // ...some vector

int* maxA                       = std::max_element(A, A + 10);
std::list<int>::iterator maxL   = std::max_element(L.begin(), L.end());
std::vector<int>::iterator maxV = std::max_element(V.begin(), V.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

In the simple case of "random access" through a vector? No.

In fact, your vector iterator is probably defined *in terms of* array access, and will be precisely as quick.

What you gain is the ability to use them in generic programming. You may not always be using a vector, and not all containers support random access.

Use iterators not only for consistency, but for *the ability to leverage template metaprogramming* that such consistency affords you.

And, if nothing else, they're a safe and helpful abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

They generalize to other collections where array[i] is much slower (i. e. lists) or even impossible (recordsets).

Also, STL algorithms use them. The STL algorithms were designed to work with any iterable collection - why exclude vectors?

The existence of two iterators - one `const` and the other not - is motivated by the way const references work in C++. If all you have is a `const` ref to a vector, why should you be able to change the stuff inside? Thus `const_iterator`. The regular `iterator` returns a writable reference to an element.

Comment: .. and now the C++ Standard algorithms, which is what the OP's actually using.

Answer (score -1):

Iterators is a generic concept. They work on all sorts of containers and have similar interface.

Accessing the array element directly like `arr_int[i]` is definitely faster because it directly translates to pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Usually iterators of `std::vector` simply wrap a pointer (in some implementation they may even *be* pointers), so, after the optimization stage, even in this case you're just doing pointer arithmetic.

Comment: apparently I made the comment without thinking too much about it, which is kinda like the whole point. it deserves a vote-down. Sorry guys!