# QString::startWith() & QStringList::removeAll() not behaving as expected

Tags: c++, qt

I have two lists.  Both containing the same values:

```
 QStringList filePaths;
 filePaths.append("C:/backup");
 filePaths.append("C:/download/file1");
 filePaths.append("D:");
 filePaths.append("C:/program");
 filePaths.append("C:/download");

 QStringList refinedPaths;

 int size = filePaths.size();

 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
   refinedPaths.append(filePaths.at(i));
 }

 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
   QString str1 = filePaths.at(i);

   for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
   {
     QString str2 = filePaths.at(j);

     if(str2 == str1)
     {
       continue;
     }

     if(str2.startsWith(str1))
     {
       refinedPaths.removeAll(str2);
     }
   }
 }
```

What I'm expecting to happen is:
 * Iterate through the strings in list, comparing every item in the list with each other.
 * If string1 starts with string2 (string2 is therefore the parent directory of string1) 
 * remove that string from the 'refined' stringlist.

Howver, what is happening is that `if(str2.startsWith(str1))` is returning true every time, and `refinedPaths.removeAll(str2);` doesn't remove any of the strings in the list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, not sure what problem you are referring to. Using your code here's the output I got

```
C:/backup
D:
C:/program
C:/download
```

A few things to improve,

1. instead of copying QStringList element by element you can just use the copy constructor i.e copying from filePaths to refinedPaths `QStringList refinedPaths(filePaths);`
2. use iterators instead of iterating by size().

   ```
   QStringList refinedPaths(filePaths);

   for(QStringList::const_iterator itr1 = filePaths.begin(); filePaths.end() != itr1 ; ++itr1)
   {

     for(QStringList::const_iterator itr2 = filePaths.begin(); filePaths.end() != itr2 ; ++itr2)
     {
       if(*itr1 == *itr2)
       {
         continue;
       }

       if(itr2->startsWith(*itr1))
       {
         refinedPaths.removeAll(*itr2);
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: I can see the code working now - I think the variables in QtCreator's debugging mode do not update while inside a for loop, or something.  Why do you suggest the use of iterators over what I have done?

Comment: For lists generally .size() operation is O(n) but QStringLists are implemented using arrayLists and the size() operation is O(1) I believe. Iterators minimize possibility of out-of-bounds errors, most existing algorithms use iterators as input. A more detailed answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131241/why-use-iterators-instead-of-array-indices

Answer (score 2):

Snippet below rationalises the list as required in place.

```
   foreach (const QString& path, filePaths)
   {
      foreach (const QString& other, filePaths)
      {
         if (other != path && other.startsWith(path))
            filePaths.removeOne (other);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    filePaths.sort();
    for (int k = 0; k < filePaths.size(); )
    {
        const QString & path = filePaths[k];
        while(k+1 < filePaths.size() && filePaths.at(k+1).startsWith(path))
            filePaths.removeAt(k+1);
        k++;
    }
```

About 3 times faster on the given data