# iterator vs. subscript

Tags: c++

I have a question about the preference between iterator and subscripting. For example, if I am doing something like:

```
for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != ivec.size(); ++i) {
  ivec[i] related operation
}

for (vector<int>::iterator it = ivec.begin(); it != ivec.end(); ++it) {
  *it related operation
}
```

Which one is preferred? In the perspective of:
1. Performance
2. Clarity
3. Other concerns?

I am aware this question have been previously discussed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131241/why-use-iterators-instead-of-array-indices). But in the other post it only talked about the performance cost of size();

Suppose this is about vector, and the cost of size() is negligible.

what about cost of using subscript vs. iterator?

Thanks.

Comment: @Rapptz I am not very satisfied with answer there

Comment: @AlanShore There are 24 answers there, surely one meets your standards.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate, similar questions have been asked [15 times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+iterator+vs+indices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfomance: with vector in most cases these cases are equal, since `vector<T>::iterator` is really pointer to `T` in most cases.

Clarity: work with iterator.

Comment: Even better, C++11: `for ( auto i : ivec )`

Comment: @us2012 even better `for (auto& i : ivec)` or `(const auto& i : ivec)` if we talking about T, not simply `int`.