# Value assigned by double default constructor in c++

Tags: c++, double

I have this variable:
`std::map<std::string, double> courses;`

And I'd like to print it if it has a value assigned for some key. So my keys are strings, so I want something like:

```
std::cin >> mystring;
if (!(courses[mystring] == x)) std::cout << courses[mystring] << std::endl;
```

but I don't know what to make x. Any ideas?

Comment: Default constructor for a numeric type gives 0.

Comment: Hmmm, so doing `if (!(courses[mystring] == 0))` would be a solution?

Comment: Sadly no, because the value 0 might actually be stored in the map for mystring.

Comment: @captainjamie: There is no point to use indices here.

Comment: ^ That's what I was thinking. Seems the `find` suggestions will be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do `courses.find(mystring) != courses.end()`.

Comment: @dlf: The C++ way would be to use iterators in this case.

Comment: @staticx: since when did needless complexity become "the C++ way".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I'm not going to debate it here.. maybe in chat. But here's a question from 2008 with some good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131241/why-use-iterators-instead-of-array-indices

Comment: @staticx: the selected "solution" for that question, talking about indexing of `std::list` as if code that did that could be inefficient, is a good example of SO as Herb Schildt-land. other than that I fail to see any relevance to your assertion here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach

```
auto it = courses.find( mystring );

if ( it != courses.end() ) std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
```

An alternative is to use member function `count`. It is even simpler than using method find because there is no need to define the iterator.

```
if ( courses.count( mystring ) ) std::cout << courses[mystring]  << std::endl;
```

Or even it would be better to write

```
if ( courses.count( mystring ) != 0 ) std::cout << courses[mystring]  << std::endl;
```

Comment: It may seem simpler, but find seems much more intuitive to me :)

Comment: @staticx It requires to define an iterator. So the code is more compound with find. Using count you can write only one line of code as in the example in my post.

Comment: `return courses.find(mystring) != courses.end();` is one line too.

Comment: @staticx  In this case it is not clear why you tried to get the iterator that returned by method find.

Comment: I would agree if you didn't know why a C++ programmer would see if the result of find was equal to `end`. But then you probably need more training if you don't understand that.

Comment: @staticx Returning objects of fundamental types is much cheaper than returning objects of class types.

Comment: I don't know much an iterator costs, so I will take your word for it

Comment: @staticx Function find builds and returns an iterator and moreover you need to call other member function end() that to compare it with the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map::find` to check if there is an item in the map corresponding to a key.

```
std::map<std::string, double>::iterator iter = courses.find(mystring);
if ( iter != courses.end() )
{
  std::cout << iter->second << std::endl;
}
```

Using `find` and using the returned iterator makes more sense to me since you have to search for the item only once.

Using something like:

```
if( courses.count( mystring ) )
{
    cout << courses[mystring]  << endl;
}
```

has the advantage that the code is simpler. However, it potentially comes at a cost. You may have to search for the item twice.

Comment: How does this help what has already been posted? It's practically a duplicate answer.

Comment: @staticx The answer is pretty easy, so I imagine a bunch of people were all writing it at the same time. There'd be another duplicate from me if I hadn't noticed Luchian's (then) new answer right before I clicked submit.

Comment: @staticx I agree with you. That's an unfortunate side effect of answering SO questions in real time. We start typing answers at the same time and due to various reasons, they show up in different order. I assure you I didn't copy one of the answers.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote it, but it would be nice if you could add more to differentiate yourself.

Comment: Re "You have to search for the item twice.", a map implementation is free to store the last found iterator value as hint for the next search, reducing that to O(1) in this case. E.g. see the complexity of [`std::map::emplace_hint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint). That alone classifies this optimization consideration as **premature**, and additionally there is the order-of-magnitude difference between i/o and searching in a small collection, not to mention the complexity (addition variable) and verbosity of the iterator based code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That's an interesting piece of knowledge. I didn't know that. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( courses.count( mystring ) )
{
    cout << courses[mystring]  << endl;
}
```

Don't optimize prematurely, just write what's simplest and most clear.

I.e. using [`count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count), <sup>[1]</sup>as above.

In this case an optimization using more convoluted and verbose code with [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) would be extremely <sup>[2]</sup>marginal, since reuse of an iterator can't in general compare to the time involved in i/o, so I advice against that.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>) You can add a comparision with 0 or e.g. a `!!` conversion to `bool`, if the old C convention of using a number directly as a boolean looks cryptic or weird.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup>) One might think that using `count` would force a redundant second search for the item, but a map implementation is free to store the last found iterator value as hint for the next search, reducing that to O(1) in this case. E.g. see the complexity of [`std::map::emplace_hint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint). That alone classifies this optimization consideration as premature, and additionally there is the order-of-magnitude difference between i/o and searching in a small collection, not to mention the complexity (additional variable) and verbosity of the iterator based code.</sup>