# Use of vector iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

This is more of a conceptual doubt. I am learning to use vectors in C++.

While iterating through a vector, I could do it in two ways:

```
vector<int> temp;
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){     
    temp.push_back(j);
}

int sum1 = 0;
int sum2 = 0;

//Method 1: almost treating it like an array
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
    sum1 = sum1 + temp[i];
}

//Method 2: using an iterator
vector<int>::iterator it;
for(it = temp.begin(); it < temp.end(); it++) {     
    sum2 = sum2 + *it;
}
```

Both methods worked fine and yielded expected results. However, I have noticed that most of the suggested codes (on stackexchange, etc) use  iterators. Is there any specific reason for that or is it just out of convenience?

Comment: Let me add that iterators are usually slightly slower than the raw access, if such access is available.

Answer (score 0):

Iterators are more generic. Using iterators you can use *any* class supporting iterators. If you use "method 1" then you're limited to vectors and `std::array`.

I would even go further and stop using `container.begin()` and `container.end()`, and instead use [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) (if iterators are needed) or the [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Answer (score 0):

First option is preferred when size of the vector is small.
Moreover, if you're not planning to use it to alter the contents of the vector, then why use it ? Use Iterator instead.

Read this for clarification.
[Why use iterators instead of array indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131241/why-use-iterators-instead-of-array-indices)

Comment: Thanks! That links helps a lot!